# Count the number of multiple values in a single column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a long list of string values that I would like to count, in one particular column of a table.  I know this works for counting all unique values.

```
SELECT
    code_id ,
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
    mydb
GROUP BY
    code_id
ORDER BY
    code_id
```

I only have a certain selection of values to count, therefore do now want all.  My list is long, but for example, if I just wanted to count the numbers of strings 'ax1', 'c39', and 'x1a' in my code_id column?  I've seen examples with multiple lines of code, one for each value which will be huge for counting many values.  I'm hoping for something like :

```
SELECT
    code_id ,
    COUNT(* = ('ax1, 'c39', 'x1a')) AS num
FROM
    mydb
GROUP BY
    code_id
ORDER BY
    code_id
```

Desired output would be

```
code_id    count
ax1         39
c39         42
x1a          0
```

Is there an easy way, rather than a line of code for each value to be counted?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `CTE` that returns all the string values and a `LEFT` join to your table to aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT code_id FROM (VALUES ('ax1'), ('c39'), ('x1a')) c(code_id))
SELECT c.code_id, 
       COUNT(t.code_id) AS num
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.code_id = c.code_id
GROUP BY c.code_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42e0dea966c3e04cf62b6dc65313cfad).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
SELECT
    code_id ,
    sum(1) AS num
FROM Mydb
WHERE code_id in ('ax1', 'c39', 'x1a')
GROUP BY code_id
ORDER BY code_id
```

Comment: This will not return 0 if 'x1a' does not exist in the table.

Comment: You’re right @forpas, I misread the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If pivot output is acceptable you might use:

```
select
  count(case when code_id = 'ax1' then 1 end) [ax1],
  count(case when code_id = 'c39' then 1 end) [c39],
  count(case when code_id = 'x1a' then 1 end) [x1a]
 from mydb
```